# How to replace existing native Android/iOS app with Flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have existing Android and iOS native app on playstore for one of our product. These apps are having offline functionality. So currently users may have some data stored on their devices for these apps.

I am checking feasibility to create these apps with Flutter and replace those on respective play stores.

My query is, is it possible to provide some kind of migration or mechanism to move native mobile app db into flutter app db?

Comment: You can provide an update to your existing app which will provide users with an option to export their data (to a convenient format such as json/yaml). In your new app, you can then give the option to "import" that data.

Comment: In what format are the data of your current app saved in? Is it a DB? Is it serialized to a file? In any case, the App's documents (where the user data are stored) don't get deleted after an update, so you should be able to migrate the data yourself

Comment: its DB. I have used GreedDao.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can migrate the app piece by piece by using a Flutter module and including it in your iOS and Android apps.

Say, for instance you were trying to replace one page in Flutter, you'd then be able to setup a `MethodChannel` to request and send data from iOS and Android to Flutter and store that data in your Flutter app database and migrate it over time.

For iOS: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup

For Android: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup

To setup a `MethodChannel` you can read through this:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab#example

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks for this answer