# is it possible to replace same mobile android native app with react native mobile app on play store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, app-store

**Replacement of app on playstore**
can we replace the same app with apk created with react native for play store

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace existing native Android/iOS app with Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53664852/how-to-replace-existing-native-android-ios-app-with-flutter-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you keep building with the **same Keystore** file it won't be a problem.

Comment: Basically, Google Play Store doesn't care how you build this APK the only thing that checks is your signing to check if it is signed by same authority and same package name.