# updating native mobile app to flutter app

Tags: ios, flutter, native

I have my native iOS and android app in App Store and play store. We used CoreData for local storage.Now we started developing flutter app with the same bundle id but we don't know how to get the local datas in flutter app when user updating native app to flutter.

don't have any idea to do this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It might be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53664852/3586084